# Stability C# Forms connected to Outlook using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have a c# forms application witch i connect to outlook.

The program processes incoming mail, and should run stable during the day.
The problem is that the program becomes unresponsive after a view hours, without a obvious reason.

I'm trying to log exceptions, but it just becomes unresponsive in the production environment.
Any idea how to resolve this issue?

The program has some class variables:

```
Outlook.Application olApp;
Outlook.NameSpace olSession;
Outlook.MAPIFolder olInbox;
Outlook.Items olInboxItems
```

I connect outlook:

```
private void InitOutlook()
{

    if (olApp == null)
        olApp = new Outlook.Application();

    olSession = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    olInbox = olSession.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    olInboxItems = olPlanonIn.Items;
    olInboxItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(InboxItemAdded);

}
```

Eventhandler for processing mails

```
private void InboxInItemAdded(object itm)
{
// process my mail
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues in a Interop-PowerPoint scenario. I never found the exact reason, but a likely supsect is the number of open COM-Objects. Are you releasing all Objects properly?

Have a look at this thread for details: [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

As a last resort you could implement a watcher thread which restarts your process. Not nice, but it may "solve" the problem.

Comment: Thanhks, i checked my code and i was still using  olInbox.Items instead of olInboxItems, just updated my tool...

Comment: Glad that I could help, that kind of crap is really annoying.